Javascript object value not getting updated
I am confused about this issue i am having
I recieve this Json object as a Websocket message from a hardware device, the property uiAppMsg is encoded in base64 so I decode it and then want to reassign it to the uiAppMsg in the jsonObj but when I run this in my app, it does not update the value of jsonObj.uiAppMsg and in the following lines i can still see its value as the encoded string, when i try to do this in JSFiddle for example it decodes the string properly and I can see the objects attribute value updated as the decoded Json Object. Am i missing something basic here why it wouldnt be working in the app. So basically I want to reassign the uiAppMsg Property on the object with the decoded string.
let socketMsg = "{\"msgType\":\"uiAppMsg\",\"uiAppMsg\":\"eyJ0cmFuc2FjdGlvbkRhdGEiOnsiQnJkU3RhdHVzRGlzcGxheSI6eyJEaXNwbGF5VGV4dCI6IkFMUkVBRFkgbmV3bGluZSBPTkJPQVJEIiwidGltZXIiOiIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiJ9fSwidHJhbnNhY3Rpb25UaW1lb3V0RGF0YSI6eyJCcmRTdGF0dXNEaXNwbGF5Ijp7IkRpc3BsYXlUZXh0IjoiIiwidGltZXIiOiIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiJ9fX0=\"}"
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(socketMsg);
const decodedUIAppMsg = atob(jsonObj.uiAppMsg);
jsonObj.uiAppMsg = JSON.parse(decodedUIAppMsg);

console.log(jsonObj)



hmm can you try jsonObj = {...jsonObj, uiAppMsg: JSON.parse(decodedUIAppMsg)}

If it's working in another place (like JSFiddle or console), the issue is not the re-assignment itself. Provide a proper reproduction of your issue, otherwise no one will be able to properly help you.

You aren't missing anything basic: in fact your code works in firefox debugger. It's possible that your platform is returning you something read-only from JSON.parse - perhaps it has a lazy-evaluating implementation. As cmgchess suggests, constructing a new object with your change would solve that.

i had this suspicion because of the angular tag. maybe it doesnt detect the change since the reference hasnt changed. but i maybe wrong

@cmgchess it is an angular application and i wanted to clarify about what you said, if i just did jsonObj.uiAppMsg = JSON.parse(decodedUIAppMsg);  like i showed above Javascript ignores it since the reference hasnt changed? but reassigning it with {...jsonObj, } updates it to a new object?

for objects and arrays it works that way

Both JSON.stringify and atob should work in Angular.
Here are two alternatives that use destructuring/spread, and a functional approach that reduces the object.


let socketMsg = "{\"msgType\":\"uiAppMsg\",\"uiAppMsg\":\"eyJ0cmFuc2FjdGlvbkRhdGEiOnsiQnJkU3RhdHVzRGlzcGxheSI6eyJEaXNwbGF5VGV4dCI6IkFMUkVBRFkgbmV3bGluZSBPTkJPQVJEIiwidGltZXIiOiIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiJ9fSwidHJhbnNhY3Rpb25UaW1lb3V0RGF0YSI6eyJCcmRTdGF0dXNEaXNwbGF5Ijp7IkRpc3BsYXlUZXh0IjoiIiwidGltZXIiOiIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiJ9fX0=\"}";

// In-line
// =======
const { uiAppMsg, ...obj } = JSON.parse(socketMsg);
const result1 = { ...obj, uiAppMsg: JSON.parse(atob(uiAppMsg))  };
console.log(result1);

// Reusable function
// =================
const parseMsgAndDecodeFields = (msg, fields) =>
  fields.reduce((result, field) =>
    Object.assign(obj, {
      [field]: JSON.parse(atob(result[field]))
    }), JSON.parse(msg));
const result2 = parseMsgAndDecodeFields(socketMsg, ['uiAppMsg']);
console.log(result2);
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



